# How to use return instead echo to output html?

Tags: php, html, return, echo

I have a function...

```
$post_text .= '<div style="font-size: 15px; color: blueviolet">';
$post_text .= "<br>";
$post_text .= 'Text number 1.';
$post_text .= "<br>";
$post_text .= 'Text number 2.';
$post_text .= "<br>";
$post_text .= 'Text number 3, <a href="urlr">Text number 4.</a>';
$post_text .= '</div>';

echo $post_text;
```

This works well when used with `echo $post_text;`, but how do I make this function work with `return $post_text;` without returning html as a plain text.

Comment: Welcome. This is a bit unclear. What "function" are you referring to? What you posted isn't one.

Comment: Hi. It is to append post text inside phpbb software.
Function is to big, it is actually an plugin I am trying to customize on my way, so I can't post all the code, but the point is, I need to use ".=" php operator to append existing text, but also to make appended html to not show as plain text.

Comment: What do you mean by: 'without returning html as a plain text.'?  Html is plain text.

Comment: <br> shows as <br>, it does not act as an actual new line separator, I meant on that.

Comment: Here is the whole script https://pastebin.com/DB6TY0W9 the change needs to be done, on this part $post_text .= "\n\n" . '[url=' . $rss_item['link'] . ']' . $this->user->lang('FPB_READ_MORE') . '[/url]';

Answer (score 1):

if you have :

```
function text(){
$post_text .= '<div style="font-size: 15px; color: blueviolet">';
$post_text .= "<br>";
$post_text .= 'Text number 1.';
$post_text .= "<br>";
$post_text .= 'Text number 2.';
$post_text .= "<br>";
$post_text .= 'Text number 3, <a href="urlr">Text number 4.</a>';
$post_text .= '</div>';

return $post_text;
}

echo text();
```

You shouldn't have any issues, maybe it is another thing in your code that is causing the issue ( maybe the framework ? );

Comment: If You want to return only text you could do use strip_tags()
(https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: Ask for clarification in/on the question.

Comment: Ok, but, well... in my case it is not echo text(); but return text();, it is huge script to post everything, and problem is there is no single echo in it, but all return, and than I get html showing as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function:

```
function post_text(){
$post_text .= '<div style="font-size: 15px; color: blueviolet">';
$post_text .= "<br>";
$post_text .= 'Text number 1.';
$post_text .= "<br>";
$post_text .= 'Text number 2.';
$post_text .= "<br>";
$post_text .= 'Text number 3, <a href="urlr">Text number 4.</a>';
$post_text .= '</div>';
return $post_text;
}
```

Such that you could call the function which would immediately output the return value:

```
'<div class="main-container"><?php echo post_text(); ?></div>'
```

This will be returned as plain text since the values you passed into the php variables are strings, but will be parsed as html when the function is called.